# Is there a fast way of pixel-by-pixel proceccing images in PHP

Tags: php, image, performance

I apply my own algotirhm on images in PHP.
The algorithm goes on three input images pixel by pixel (all images of the same size) and sets the pixel in the output image:

```
for ($x = 0; $x < $width; $x++)
{
  for ($y = 0; $y < $height; $y++)
  {
    $color1 = imagecolorat ($image1, $x, $y);
    $color2 = imagecolorat ($image2, $x, $y);
    $color3 = imagecolorat ($image3, $x, $y);

    $color4 = my_function ($color1, $color2, $color3);

    imagesetpixel ($image4, $x, $y, $color4);
   }
}
```

The problem is that this is really slow for large images, because of PHP being an interpreted language.

There are special methods in PHP which allow efficiently call a function for all members of array, like: array_map, array_filter, array_reduce, array_walk.

Are there similar methods for images, i.e. call some function for all pixels of one (or several) images?

Or maybe there is a way to access image as an array in PHP?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP slow on string joining?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8294231/php-slow-on-string-joining)

Comment: You could make a roundtrip over the XBM format (needs manual transformation into a binary string again), if your GD library supported it. But the it's really the loops that are slow. Working on a stringy array won't help much.

Answer (score 1):

> There are special methods in PHP which allow efficiently call a function for all members of array

You are wrong with this statement, I am afraid.
These functions aren't that efficient.

Anyway, no - there are no similar functions for the GD library.

You can search google for some pixel access library - there may be some already written, I believe.