# Are there image processing libraries for PHP that'd allow manipulating images on a pixel by pixel basis like MATLAB?

Tags: php, image-processing, dct

I'm working on a project that might require me to compute the DCT of the image. Hence the question.

Comment: If you need to make this computation repeatedly as part of a web app, doing it pixel-by-pixel in PHP will be extremely slow.

Comment: @japreiss I want an Android app to take an image, send it to a server for processing and then get the processed image back. Do you have anything else in mind that I could use for image processing on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-> [Is there a fast way of pixel-by-pixel proceccing images in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8294579/is-there-a-fast-way-of-pixel-by-pixel-proceccing-images-in-php)

I think it would be best to process the files using another language instead of PHP or library/application such as - ImageMagick php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php. 
I've never used this myself, so don't really know performance issues.
Also -> wideimage.sourceforge.net/
The GD functions, as described in the previous answer, are quite slow, and sometimes can take a huge chunk of the CPU for processing.

Take a look here for seperate benchmarks etc:
http://kore-nordmann.de/blog/comparison_of_php_image_libraries_update.html

Answer (score 0):

GD has per-pixel operations, but they're not particularly fast: [imagecolorat()](http://php.net/imagecolorat) and [imagesetpixel()](http://php.net/imagesetpixel)