# Why can't one do image processing with PHP?

Tags: php, performance, image, math, processor

I'm doing basic pixel-by-pixel processing on a 500x500px image. Regardless of what equation I put in, if it doesn't run out of memory, it does it in a awful amount of time.

Compare this script:

```
define('STARTED_AT',microtime(true));
set_time_limit(0);

function calculatesomething(){ return abs(100-round(pow(15/150,2)))+pow(2,4) - calculatesomething2(); }
function calculatesomething2(){ return abs(100-round(pow(15/150,2)))+pow(2,4) - calculatesomething3(); }
function calculatesomething3(){ return abs(100-round(pow(15/150,2)))+pow(2,4); }

$r = array();
foreach(range(1,pow(10,5)) as $x){
    foreach(range(1,4) as $y)
        $r[] = calculatesomething();
}

$o = (microtime(true)-STARTED_AT);
echo 'took '.$o.'ms to finish';
```

**took 38.847129106522s to finish**

And this one:

```
define('STARTED_AT',microtime(true));
set_time_limit(0);

function calculatesomething(){ return abs(100-round(pow(15/150,2)))+pow(2,4) - calculatesomething2(); }
function calculatesomething2(){ return abs(100-round(pow(15/150,2)))+pow(2,4) - calculatesomething3(); }
function calculatesomething3(){ return abs(100-round(pow(15/150,2)))+pow(2,4); }

$r = array();
foreach(range(1,pow(10,5)) as $x){
    $r[] = abs(100-round(pow(15/150,2)))+pow(2,4) - ( abs(100-round(pow(15/150,2)))+pow(2,4) - ( abs(100-round(pow(15/150,2)))+pow(2,4) ));
    $r[] = abs(100-round(pow(15/150,2)))+pow(2,4) - ( abs(100-round(pow(15/150,2)))+pow(2,4) - ( abs(100-round(pow(15/150,2)))+pow(2,4) ));
    $r[] = abs(100-round(pow(15/150,2)))+pow(2,4) - ( abs(100-round(pow(15/150,2)))+pow(2,4) - ( abs(100-round(pow(15/150,2)))+pow(2,4) ));
    $r[] = abs(100-round(pow(15/150,2)))+pow(2,4) - ( abs(100-round(pow(15/150,2)))+pow(2,4) - ( abs(100-round(pow(15/150,2)))+pow(2,4) ));
}

$o = (microtime(true)-STARTED_AT);
echo 'took '.$o.'ms to finish';
```

**took `29`.651962041855s to finish**

Only hard-coded the nested iteration and extra function calls and gained `9` ms. I have a 2.4GHz dual-core and 4GB of RAM; shouldn't things run different? What can I do to improve PHP's calculation power?

Comment: You shouldn't use PHP for this kind of things. PHP just wasn't made to handle large calculations.

Comment: Why do you want to use PHP ? PHP is not for programming. Use MATLAB or Python or C++.

Comment: 38.84 and 29.65 miliseconds? That's not a long time! Also, PHP uses system calls to do math, so I don't believe there is anything you can do to "increase" the power of PHP calculations. You might need to increase memory allowances for PHP, see php.ini memory_limit.

Comment: You can write a module for php in C =) Also, unrolling short loops may increase speed by 10-20% even in C.

Comment: @BenAshton it's seconds not milliseconds, my bad.

Comment: PHP is a general processing language, which means you can do image processing, as it could do speech recognition or guiding rockets to the moon, but because it's general purpose it wouldn't do any of them well. Specialised tasks are best programmed in specialised languages explicitly designed for that purpose... plus your code is badly written making unnecessary function calls several times in each iteration of the loop... not good to create a test where you're explicitly targetting failure, and then complain when it does.

Comment: @MarkBaker `C` is general purpose language too, but it is not bad in many fields.

Comment: @MarkBaker those function calls are unnecessary because I rushed into writing an example. I actually took the first example and removed `calculatesomething2` & `calculatesomething3` and saw no drastic improvements.

Comment: @kirilloid and PHP has it's own specialist fields as well. My point is, pick a language for its strengths, not for its weaknesses; and don't use the wrong language for the task that you're doing

Comment: @MarkBaker too bad I only know PHP...

Comment: @user608886 - use real world examples.... don't simply calculate the same complex mathematical formula with the same data each time round. Even in a language like C, I'd criticise if you did pow(15/150,2) a million times instead of calculating it once. nTo be honest, this discussion is rapidly turning into a "we all hate PHP" type discussion.... voting for closure as argumentative

Comment: FWIW, your first code takes about 5.8 seconds, and your second example takes about 4.2 seconds on my I3@2.53GHZ.

Comment: Take a look at Hiphop. It's a PHP > C++ source code transformer that Facebook developed. It will convert your PHP code to C++ that you can compile and should run much faster than interpreted script.

Comment: @AndrewR doesn't run on Windows and will never do. But thank you anyways.

Comment: Most benchmarks show PHP *(and Ruby/Python/Perl)* as being 1-2 orders of magnitude slower than natively-compiled code for tight-loop computations like this.  So that is why, really.

Comment: *Any* "bytcode" interpreted language is going to run significantly slow than C++, Fortran on other compiled language.  The PHP interpreter runs at ~20-40 M opcodes/sec.  The equivalent C++ will be at least 2 orders faster.  OK, if you are doing loads of work in library routines, this gap is closed, but you aren't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One CAN do image processing with PHP - I do it frequently and suits my requirements oh so sweet.

It all depends what your space and time constraints are.

If doing it in PHP on a server via a browser request does not cut it then you need to review your algorithms and then your tools.

You have many options but you need to give a real use case before anyone can guide you.

Answer (score 0):

After zaf's response I did some more digging and found
[PHP slow on string joining?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8294231/php-slow-on-string-joining)

I was using `array('row1'=>array('col1'=> array($r,$g,$b), [...]), [...])` to store pixel values. Looks like bitwise operations work a lot faster and I'll go with those instead.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a high level, flexible easy to use language, but the price you pay for that ease of use is speed.  There's a lot going on behind the scenes to support that flexibility, even when it's not really needed, like in your example.

Pixel by pixel processing is a classic task for a low level, close to the metal language like C or C++.  You might want to look into writing a PHP extension in C if you need the speed.

Answer (score 0):

After 9 hours of tedious research I finally found ImageMagick's ::fxImage function which does it! Pixel-by-pixel processing with math.

Man, I feel so relief I'd smash a watermelon into a cliff like in Ice Age.

http://www.imagemagick.org/script/fx.php

Thanks everyone!